# Django queryset time interval

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to make object selections in my database by time interval

currently i found a method to select only objects from a day but not from an interval with this:

```py
data.filter(end_at__day=datetime.datetime.now().day)
```

I saw this on the django __gte documentation which means from a date until today but I failed to make it work

> [image]

I have try this:

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DashboardSettingsForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dis_planned = form.cleaned_data.get('display_planned')
            dis_currently = form.cleaned_data.get('display_currently')
            dis_ended = form.cleaned_data.get('display_ended')
            end_at = start_at = datetime.now()

            if dis_ended:
                end_at = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)
            if dis_planned:
                start_at = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=12)
            data = data.filter(start_at__gt=start_at, end_at__gt=end_at)
            print(f"interval: start{start_at} end{end_at}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.filter(start_at__gt=start_at, end_at__gt=end_at)
```

The above line means the objects need to satisfy:

1. `start_at`s that are ***later*** than `datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)`
2. `end_at`s that are ***later*** than `datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=12)`

So you need to use the reverse (`lt`) for `end_at`, to make it a filter that covers a range *within*:

```
data = data.filter(start_at__gt=start_at, end_at__lt=end_at)
```

This essentially means the objects need to meet this criteria:

1. `start_at`s that are ***later*** than `datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)`
2. `end_at`s that are ***earlier*** than `datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=12)`